# Spark Job gets stuck at 99.7%

Tags: performance, apache-spark, talend

I'm trying to perform a simple join operation using Talend & Spark. The input data set is a few million records and the look up data set is around 100 records.(we might need to join with million records look up data too).

When trying to just read the input data and generate a flat file with the following memory settings, the job works fine and takes less amount of time to run. But, when trying to perform a join operation as explained above, the job gets stuck at 99.7%.

- ExecutorMemory = 20g
- Cores Per Executor = 4
- Yarn resources allocation = Fixed
- Num of executors = 100
- spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=6000 (On some preliminary research I found that this has to be 10% of the executor memory, but that didn't help too.)

After a while(30-40 minutes) the job prints a log saying - "Lost executor xx on abc.xyz.com". This is probably because it's put on wait for too long and the executor gets killed.

I'm trying to check if anyone has run into this issue where a Spark job gets stuck at 99.7% for a simple operation. Also, what are the recommended tuning properties to use in such a scenario.